# Ubuntu issue- blank screen, inactive showing no signal

Tags: graphics, display

I have upgraded from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 19.10.

On installation, my display kept going blank- this was fixed with using nomodeset.

After install, with nomodeset all my graphics were huge and resolution was very low- so I disabled nomodeset.

After disabling nomodeset, my display randomly will go blank and inactive- showing no signal and the only way to get out of this is to hard reboot my computer.

All works fine with onboard graphics, only happens with my AMD R9 390x PCIE graphics card.

I am also running a 3440x1440p ultrawide monitor connected via display port- 21:9 aspect ratio, tried also running at 1920 x 1080p, still going blank, also reduced refresh rate to 30hz and still going blank and showing no signal.

I have also tried disabling wayland, but issue still happens.

Please help as I really want to start using Ubuntu over Windows 10 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Make sure to remove modeset from grub parameters:

```
radeon.modeset=0
```

and add

```
radeon.cik_support=0 radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.si_support=1 amdgpu.dpm=1 amdgpu.dc=1
```

Source: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=293729

Comment: so far soo good Jonata appreciate the help! :D